# Formula to look in first column before heading

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, ifs

I am currently using a function in **Column J** as below
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(Vlookup(if(U3:U<>"",(if(U3:U<5,"Hot",if(U3:U<10,"Warm",if(U3:U<30,"Cold",if(U3:U>30,"Lost"))))),),CellRef!A1:B,2,0)))

**Column U** contains Numerical data which return the value accordingly via vlookup,
But what if i want the function to look into **Column L** first and if data found return value, if nothing is found in **Column L** it should start looking into **Column U**.

p.s. **Column L** already contains text and not numbers

sheet link here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dXZlC4i_l1WGCp6tbiXUFPhYBr3oc7b0V0sUbzG313M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you could create a new lookup array formed by the cartesian product of your current arrays and work with that.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dXZlC4i_l1WGCp6tbiXUFPhYBr3oc7b0V0sUbzG313M/edit?usp=sharing

sheet link here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ifs()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      ifs( 
        len(L3:L), L3:L, 
        V3:V = "", iferror(1/0), 
        V3:V < 5, "Hot", 
        V3:V < 11, "Warm", 
        V3:V < 30, "Cold", 
        V3:V >= 30, "Lost" 
      ), 
      CellRef!A1:B, 
      columns(CellRef!A1:B), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dXZlC4i_l1WGCp6tbiXUFPhYBr3oc7b0V0sUbzG313M/edit#gid=1754032817).